# SQL Stored procedure - Grouping Sets with a where clause possible?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, grouping-sets

I have used `Grouping Sets` before to sum up everything in a column to get a **grand total**.

But, I have not found a way to sum up the columns with a `WHERE CLAUSE` included and I was wondering if there is actually a way to do this using `Grouping Sets`?

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of a basic query:
I want to be able to sum up everything where `Deleted = 0`. Because I do not want the **deleted transactions** to be included in the **Grand Total**. But I still want the deleted transactions to show up in the result.

```
SELECT 
  TP.CompanyID, 
  TP.CompanyName, 
  TP.PaidStatus,'
  TP.Credit,
  TP.Debit,
  TP.Outstanding,
  TP.Deleted                           

FROM    
  dbo.Posting TP

GROUP BY
GROUPING SETS(( 
   CompanyID,
   CompanyName,
   PaidStatus,
   Credit,
   Debit,
   OutStanding,
   Deleted),())
```

Comment: Can't you add 1) old, working query, 2) query attempt?

Comment: Yes give us your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Where clause with GROUPING SETS like below:

It should work.

```
SELECT 
  TP.CompanyID, 
  TP.CompanyName, 
  TP.PaidStatus,'
  TP.Credit,
  TP.Debit,
  TP.Outstanding,
  TP.Deleted                           

FROM    
  dbo.Posting TP
WHERE TP.Deleted = 0
GROUP BY
GROUPING SETS(( 
   CompanyID,
   CompanyName,
   PaidStatus,
   Credit,
   Debit,
   OutStanding,
   Deleted),())
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I want the Deleted to show but not be calculated